# 12.04.4 server can't verify common SSL certificates, usual fixes failing

Tags: server, security, ssl, curl, certificates

## The Problem

I've got one server in a farm which is suddenly unable to correctly handle SSL certificates. Attempting to do a curl command like `curl -v https://google.com` results in:

```
curl -v https://google.com
* About to connect() to google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.137.101... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Using `openssl s_client` is a little more detailed.

```
# openssl s_client -host google.com -port 443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

### Things Tried So Far

- Reinstalling `ca-certificates` - already have the latest available version, according to `aptitude`, `Version: 20130906ubuntu0.12.04.1`.
- Reconfiguring `ca-certificates` via `dpkg-reconfigure`. This appears to rehash the `/etc/ssl/certs` folder but has no effect on the problem.
- Using `update-ca-certificates --fresh` to regenerate the symbolic links in that folder
- Grabbing the latest Mozilla ca bundle from `curl.haxx.se` - by putting that .pem file in `/etc/ssl/certs` and running the update command.

### Weirdness

The certificate that `curl` claims it cannot find is indeed in the certification path.

```
# ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/*Geo*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Apr  7 15:57 /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt
...
```

The certificate file referenced has the same permissions as every other box on my network, namely 644.

```
# ls -l /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1216 Feb 20 11:49 /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt
```

Other secure sites such as Github show identical issues with different certificates. I am running the absolute latest version available of all packages for Ubuntu 12.04.4, including `curl`, `openssl`, and `ca-certificates`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem stopped happening after a couple updates. It looks like the ca-certificates file provided in the Ubuntu repos was missing an intermediate cert for GeoTrust.

Comment: Nope. Last change for `ca-certificates` was February 2014. See its [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20130906ubuntu2/changelog). Are you sure you are still seeing the same certificate chain offered by the Google server? Google tends to rotate certificates, change support for ECC now and then, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem, try this:

`openssl s_client -host google.com -port 443`

this command will also print a cert chain, the last one is:

`s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA`

`i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority`

so you also need https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem.

This cert path is different with cert path showed in browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome), I don't know why, but this fix my problem.